# AngularJs: Its posible call my controllers in one js file?

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angular-config

I have many controllers, so i want to call all of them in one js file in my html document for example: 
And in that file call all my controllers

Comment: What do you mean by calling a controller? You mean executing the controller function?

Comment: You can create your controllers in a single JS file and use it for your web application. We separate controllers in different files for separation of concern and easier maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all your controllers to a single file and call that file from HTML.

To concatenate, Gulp or Grunt or Webpack can be used.